# Setting RowHeight Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I've been struggling for several hours to set row heights for an implied range.  The code works *except* for two problems 1. ALL rows with data are set to `AutoFit` instead of just the intended range and 2. I cannot seem to add '3' to the row height per the 2nd to last line of code:

```
Sub SetRH()

    ActiveSheet.Unprotect
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Range("C" & (ActiveCell.row)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Range(Selection.Offset(0, 0), Selection.Offset(0, 4)).Select

    Selection.sort Key1:=Range("C6"), Order1:=xlAscending, Key2:=Range("E6") _
       , Order2:=xlAscending, Key3:=Range("D6"), Order3:=xlAscending, Header _
        :=xlGuess, OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom

    For Each row In ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows: Rows.AutoFit: Next
    For Each row In ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows: Rows.RowHeight = Rows.RowHeight + 3: Next

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: You need to comment out the `For Each .AutoFit` or delete the line. Rows are initially set to 12.75 points high; to set your `row.height` don't use +, just put the number in points you want it to be, like `Row.Height = 15`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  That won't accomplish what I'm trying to do... I want the rows to be an implied height as there can be one to four lines and I'm trying to make the spreadsheet look uniform.  'RowHeight +' does work, just not in this case.

Comment: One to four lines because some cells are wrapped if that wasn't clear.  I can make this run through an explicit range, but not implied... it seems not to like any of the objects I feed it.

Comment: I under stand what you want, see my answer.

Comment: Thanks!  That is working, but only if my range starts at "A1".  I'm trying to imply it like this: Range("C" & (ActiveCell.row)).Select - Can you tell me how that's done?

Comment: it is working on first row only with this     Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Dim lRow As Long
    Range("C" & (ActiveCell.row)).Select
    lRow = ws.Range("C" & ActiveCell.row).CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
    
    For i = 1 To lRow
        ws.Range("C" & i).Rows.AutoFit
        ws.Range("C" & i).Rows.RowHeight = ws.Range("C" & i).Rows.RowHeight + 3
    Next i

Comment: sorry, I have no idea how to format that properly.

Comment: See my edit to use active cell to last row in column.

Answer (score 3):

The below code will loop through each row auto fit and then increase the row height by +3.

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveSheet

Dim Rng As Range
Dim cel As Range
Set Rng = Range(ActiveCell, Cells(Rows.Count, ActiveCell.Column).End(xlUp))

For Each cel In Rng
    cel.Rows.AutoFit
    cel.Rows.RowHeight = cel.Rows.RowHeight + 3
Next cel
```

Comment: Right on, thanks much!   Also a lot easier for me to follow.

Comment: I'm glad i could help, i never used `RowHeight +` before, i appreciate the chance to figure it out.

Comment: cool, it works with other operators also.  I tried *1.2 first, but it of course didn't result in uniform spacing.  form looks awesome!